# Symfony2 Sonata admin make apache goes down on Windows 7

Tags: apache, symfony, windows-7, sonata-admin

I'm learning Symfony and installed **Sonata Admin Bundle**. After opening /admin/login/ first time it opens, but after reload **apache goes down**. So after every page reload I need to restart apache.

I think it's my code bug, so installed working site on my local, but got same problem.

Don't know what info is important to put with question, please let me know and I'll update question.

**UPDATE:**

I got **perl** error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = (unset)
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Can find solution for *Linux*, need to run this commands:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
apt-get install locales
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

But nothing for **Windows 7**.

Also some solutions on StackOverflow:
[How to fix a locale setting warning from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-can-i-fix-a-locale-warning-from-perl)

**Solution**

Problem was in APC extension, you can disable it on your dev server, because it just extension for cahce. Works for me without it.

Comment: Check your apache log to see what it happened. Check symfony logs too. What do you have on screen? Error? Blank page?

Comment: @ibasaw you are right, I got perl error. Thanks. Updating question with error. Can't find how to fix it in Windows 7