# Based on Perl on Windows 7

Tags: windows, perl, locale, padre

I installed Padre perl, perl IDE on windows 7.And every time i run a program, i am getting an error saying,

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.

perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:

LC_ALL = (unset),

LANG = (unset)

are supported and installed on your system.

perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I get outputs, but this error message is on the top of each and every output.
i am tired of searching solutions for this problem,can some one tell me how to fix this problem ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a locale warning from perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-can-i-fix-a-locale-warning-from-perl)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because those answers are all for Linux or MacOS.

Comment: searching solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `LC_ALL` and `LANG` environment variables to `C`:

```
C:\>set LC_ALL=C
C:\>set LANG=C
C:\>perl x.pl
```

If you want to make this permanent, or work from your IDE, go to Control Panel->System and Security->System->Advanced System Settings, and under the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables. Then, add LC_ALL and LANG to the list. You might need to restart your IDE if you make changes to these variables.