# perl: warning: Setting locale failed on Windows XP/7

Tags: windows, perl, warnings, locale

On Windows XP/7 I'm suddenly getting the following warning when running scripts:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.   
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:      
LC_ALL = "C",       
LANG = "C"      
are supported and installed on your system.     
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").       
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.   
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:  
LC_ALL = "C",   
LANG = "C"  
are supported and installed on your system.     
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix this.

Edit: I'm using Perl 5.012002

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-can-i-fix-a-locale-warning-from-perl

Comment: @ialarmedalien Doesn't say what to do for Windows. Also this one is if they are unset but as you can see they are, in fact, set to C.

Comment: Looks like they're not being recognised, though. There's some more info in a linked Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846560/based-on-perl-on-windows-7