# Locale warning from Perl stops Postgres configuring

Tags: perl, postgresql, ubuntu, azure

So I want to set up Postgres on a Microsoft Azure-server running Ubuntu 14.04. I need to make a cluster:

```
user@mysystem:~$ pg_createcluster
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "nb_NO.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
```

What I've tried:

- Adding `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to `/etc/environment`
- Running `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8` (and also with my own typeset, norwegian)

After much googling I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-can-i-fix-a-locale-warning-from-perl) question and answer, which is the same situation as I have. The problem is that none of the suggestions in the accepted answer works for me, but I think that it may be that the problem pointed out with the typeset differing from my host and the Azure cloud-machine, may be the source of the problem. I haven't found anything to help me with this yet.

Note that the perl-warning comes with other Postgres-related commands too, including starting the Postgres-server or client-program.

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a stackexchange especially for ubuntu and also for unix. You might get a better answer there.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: Also, `nb_NO` is a very weird locale. It would be for an unknown country (there is none with code nb) speaking Norwegian. It looks like a typo for `no_NO` (which is Norway speaking Norwegian).

Comment: @CalleDybedahl Hm, weird. I'll try to change that too then, thanks!

Comment: @CalleDybedahl That's incorrect, `nb_NO` actually *is* the correct locale for Norwegian (Bokmål).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of connection over ssh
Add this lines to your .profile or .bashrc

```
export LC_ALL="nb_NO.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="nb_NO.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="nb_NO.UTF-8"
```