# the VM is running with native name encoding of latin1 which may cause Elixir to malfunction as it expects utf8

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, utf-8, virtual-machine, elixir

How to solve this warning being prompted every time I execute Elixir code or enter `iex`?

> warning: the VM is running with native name encoding of latin1 which may cause Elixir to malfunction as it expects utf8. Please ensure your locale is set to UTF-8 (which can be verified by running "locale" in your shell)

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US:
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Apparently unset `LC_ALL=` was the issue, I checked

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="en_US.utf8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:"
```

ensuring `LC_ALL` is missing, **to fix it, I executed:**

```
$ sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

this command added `LC_ALL` to `/etc/default/locale` file:

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG="en_US.utf8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and error is gone.

Comment: The interesting part is here: [erl_sys_common_misc.c](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/a2670f0822fc6729df956c8ec8c381340ff0a5fb/erts/emulator/sys/common/erl_sys_common_misc.c)

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, it worked for me, but I had to log out and log back in.

Comment: reconnect cli after doing above

Answer (score 11):

I'm using erlang inside a docker container and the other solutions didn't cut it. The command `update-locale` may not be available inside a docker ubuntu container, so I've stole some code that installs it from https://hub.docker.com/r/voidlock/erlang/~/dockerfile/.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends locales
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    && echo $LANG UTF-8 > /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && update-locale LANG=$LANG
```

Comment: FWIW, this didn't work for me without also setting the `LANG` environment variable w/ an `ENV` declaration. I didn't realize the existence of the environment variable at runtime was significant.

Answer (score 6):

This happens when you SSH from your Mac laptop to a Linux server (including a virtual Linux server running on your laptop). SSH forwards the `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables from the local shell to the remote shell, and some of the values used on the Mac are not valid on the Linux server.

The problem can be fixed in various ways, including installing the missing locales on the server. I recommend simply disabling the SSH environment forwarding, either on the server (remove `AcceptEnv` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) or on the laptop (remove `SendEnv` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`).

Read more in [How to fix a locale setting warning from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-to-fix-a-locale-setting-warning-from-perl/7413863)

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this when using a docker image. Adding the following line to my `Dockerfile` solved this:

```
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 5):

On centOS 7 the following worked for me:

```
localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i en_US en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Should work for most if not all RHEL distributions. Cheers!

Comment: If you aren't root just add a sudo in front. This worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

in the nix-shell this command helped me:

```
export LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
```

ref: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Locales

Answer (score 1):

For me setting the locale in my init script `/etc/init/my_start_script.conf` did the trick

```
env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
export LC_ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS did it!