# Perl warning regarding strange locale setting

Tags: shell, perl

I'm currently trying to execute a shell-script in which a perl-exection is also embedded:

```
$script_dir/gen-cfg.pl \
    --prefix="$outdir" --no-skip-sequences-without-src \
    "${!cfgset/#/${src_cfg_dir}}" \
    "${src_cfg_dir}sequences-cat1.yaml" \
    "${src_cfg_dir}sequences-cat3.yaml" \
    "${extra_args[@]}"
```

When executing the script I get the following warning:

```
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LANG = "ZZ"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

This is all part of generating config files for a C++ project you can find [here](https://github.com/MPEGGroup/mpeg-pcc-tmc13).
I already know that you can change the used locale in a .bashrc file [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499794/how-to-fix-a-locale-setting-warning-from-perl), but I cannot make sense of the ZZ as a value. I already checked if perl is installed correctly.
I'm working on Windows 10 and bash is used for executing perl scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that environment variable `LANG` is set to `ZZ`, possibly from having done

```bash
export LANG=ZZ
```

Silence the warning by fix this environment variable (e.g. by unsetting it).

Comment: Really? Cause `0` is not a valid language. And it fails for me as I would expect. (Both `perl` and `locale` warn.) You should stop setting it or unset it, or set it to a valid language.