# Perl: Setting locale failed in conda environment

Tags: perl, conda, slurm

I am running a program that requires perl installed via conda. However, whenever I am running the program I get this error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "C.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

The program will still partly run with this error but then it stops.

I use slurm so everything has to be ran via an sbatch script.
Can I change the locale settings in the sbatch script before running my program?

Comment: The program does not stop because of that. As it says, that simply means the program uses the C locale instead of C.UTF-8 (which is apparently not installed).

Comment: Re "*Can I change the locale settings*", The locale settings are simply env vars. For example, setting `LANG` to `C` would silence the warning without changing anything else.

Comment: did you search the internet before posting a question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2499794/14598633