# Unable to open GNOME-TERMINAL at cent OS 7

Tags: centos7, gnome-terminal

While try to open from XTerminal getting this error:

#Locale not supported by C library

## Using the fallback 'C' locale

#Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 9

Already try to fix this by running following commands and several reboot:

$ sudo yum update
$ sudo yum reinstall gnome-terminal

Answer (score 1):

solved for me by adding following lines at my bashrc

```
export LC_ALL="en_DK.UTF-8"
export LANG="en_DK.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="en_DK.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_DK.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"
```

got this idea from following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54488882/22680974